# Remove all characters before comma of every line in a file in python

Tags: python, file, io

I need a small function in python that would read in a file and then remove all the characters up to AND INCLUDING a comma character. so for instance the following two line file:

```
hello,my name is
john,john, mary
```

would be:

```
my name is
john, mary
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have been advised to use `re.split()` already; however, regular `split()` method of `str` should suffice as well:

```
with open('new_file', 'w') as f_out, open('my_file') as f_in:
    for line in f_in:
        new_str = ','.join(line.split(',')[1:])
        f_out.write(new_str)
```

Comment: Regular `split` is even better than what you're showing here, because you can specify the maximum number of occurrences as the second parameter: `new_str = line.split(',', 1)[1]`

Comment: @JohnY - You version is not better because it fails when no comma exists.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is called [Regular Expressions](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html). Specifically, the [split](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.split) should work well.

vals=re.split(',',string,1)

Comment: Not to split hairs (pun very intended), but calling split isn't the same as using a regex. I mean, the language defined by splitting a string on a given character input is regular, sure, but a regex is a specific means of expressing a regular language. You could just as easily have said "What you want is called a DFA", and you'd be just as half-right.

Answer (score 1):

also:

```
line = 'hello,my name is'
line[line.find(',')+1 :  ]     #find position of first ',' and slice from there
>>> 'my name is'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [partition](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition)

```
>>> foo = 'hello, my name is'
>>> foo.partition(',')[2]
' my name is'
>>> foo = 'john, john, mary'
>>> foo.partition(',')[2]
' john, mary'
>>> foo = 'test,'
>>> foo.partition(',')[2]
''
>>> foo = 'bar'
>>> foo.partition(',')[2]
''
```

Comment: this is abit messy in the case where `','` doesn't exist!

Comment: @vikki: It depends on what the OP means by "remove all characters up to and including a comma".  This could be interpreted to mean that lines without any comma should have all their characters removed (which is what this answer does).  However, it is good that you pointed out we should be thinking about edge cases, because that is what often bites us in the real world.